# Extracting integers from a ID string

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to get the number `001` from the string `UID001` (The user will always enter "UIDnnn"). I tried using `cin.get` and `cin.ignore` with delimiters but with no results. What is the most effective way to extract the integers from a string?

Comment: How are we supposed to know? Is it always "UIDnnn"? If so then a substring will do it.

Comment: Get the number part with `std::string::substr()` and use `std::stoi()` to convert it to a numerical value.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to mention it will always be "UIDnnn"

Comment: @Cheezdue Add this information to your question please. Also consider posting a [MCVE] of what you've been trying.

Comment: Why not use `sscanf`?

Comment: @BenvanGompel Straight forward, but not type safe, or manageable using exceptions on failures.

Comment: You could use `std::regex_search()`.

Comment: @Lorehead That's probably overkill.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Depends on the complexity of the format, but `sscanf()` is nice and simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the simplest c++ standard compliant solution seems to be as mentioned in my comment.

Read the ID value as a `std:string`:

```
std::string ID;
std::cin >> ID;
```

Get the substring with the number part:

```
std::string numpart = ID.substr(3);
```

Convert it to a numerical value:

```
int idnum = std::stoi(numpart);
```

Comment: Thank you, this method worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those places that `scanf` and company really work well:

```
scanf("UID%d", &number);
```

With iostreams it's a bit uglier, but I'd consider something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    char ch;
    cin.get(ch);
}
cin >> number;
```

Comment: You can use iostreams to read in the string, then parse with `sscanf()`.